# Полнотекстовый поиск sqlite3 PDO не выходит…

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite3, search

Я тут наговнокодил, но выдаёт ошибку:

Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /site.org/index.php on line 19

Вот моё поделие:

```
<?php

    $db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db');
    $termin = $_GET['termin'];
    $stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE %$termin% OR text LIKE %$termin%');
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();

?>

<form action="post">
    <input type="text" name="termin" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
<?php if (empty($termin)): ?>
    <p>Missing term!</p>
<?php elseif (strlen($termin) < 3): ?>
    <p>The term must be at least 3 characters!</p>
<?php elseif ($result < 1): ?>
    <p><?= $termin ?> not found.</p>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php foreach ($result as $row): ?>
        <p>ID: <?= $row['id'] ?></p>
        <p>Date: <?= $row['date'] ?></p>
        <p>Title: <?= $row['title'] ?></p>
        <p>Text: <?= $row['text'] ?></p>
        <p><a href="?id=<?= $row['id'] ?>">More…</a></p>
        <br />
    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Потому что `$stmt` у вас FALSE. А почему оно FALSE, читайте в документации http://php.net/manual/ru/pdo.query.php

Comment: `execute` - вызывается для подготовленных запросов. `query` - выполняет запрос сразу. в `$stmt` лежат уже результат из базы

Comment: Надобно вместо query использовать prepare? А как тогда синтаксически сформулировать запрос?

Comment: Надобно разобраться, как работает query, почитав документацию, ссылку на которую я дал выше

Comment: Хотя вообще лучше действительно использовать prepare (обязательно разобравшись в нём, разумеется)

Comment: На самом деле, execute просто повторно выполнит запрос, по крайней мере для mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильный подход:

```
// подготавливаем запрос к выполнению
$stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE ? OR text LIKE ?');
// выполняем
$stmt->execute(['%' . $termin . '%', '%' . $termin . '%']);
```

Answer (score 2):

такой вариант, судя по всему, тоже подойдет

```
$termin = $_GET['termin'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM articles WHERE title LIKE :termin OR text LIKE :termin';
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['termin' => "%$termin%"]);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Кроме этого, важно стартовать PDO вот таким кодом

```
$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
);
$db = new PDO('sqlite:data.db', null, null, $options);
```

**чтобы он мог сообщать об ошибках запроса**

Comment: Но вроде же нельзя один и тот же плейсхолдер `:termin` более одного раза использовать?

Comment: Хотя ман сообщает что "You cannot use a named parameter marker of the same name more than once in a prepared statement, __unless emulation mode is on__."

Comment: Ну я попробовал, вроде бы в обоих вариантах работает. Но сейчас почитал, лучше его избегать. Судя по всему, нативный режим для SQLite PDO не поддерживает, но вдруг включат

Comment: Спасибо большое за информацию! Для меня это весьма ценно, я нуб почти совсем. И кроме того, даже не подозревал, что ПДО надо начинать таким кодом, теперь везде изменил, где необходимо.